# Register Entity class for SonataAdminBundle under src/Entity directory

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In symfony 3.4

I am moving `Entity` folder from each bundle to new directory structure `src/Entity`

As I did is like this

1)
move Mydb.php from

`Myapp/Acme/MyBundle/Entity/Mydb.php`

to

`src/Entity/Mydb.php`

2) change the namespace in Mydb.php

`namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;`

to

`namespace App\Entity;`

3)change doctrine settings to register src/Entity folder by adding this to config.yml

```
   orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
```

then clear cache, it looks like entity class is correctly registered.

---

Now I have problem when using adminbundle

1) I added sonata admin class like this.

```
sonata.admin.mydb:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\MydbAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: mydb, label: "Mydb" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - App\Entity\Mydb
        - 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD'
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]
```

However when I list the `Mydb` entity , it says

`Class App\Entity\Mydb does not exist`

What this happens ?

it looks like `App\Entity\Mydb` is correctly registered in the system but,CRUDController can't find the class.

```
AbstractAdmin->getDatagrid()
in src/Acme/AdminBundle/Controller/CRUDController.php (line 180)
        if ($listMode = $request->get('_list_mode')) {            $this->admin->setListMode($listMode);        }                $datagrid = $this->admin->getDatagrid();        $formView = $datagrid->getForm()->createView();               // set the theme for the current Admin Form        $this->setFormTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFilterTheme());
```

---

My solution.

@Koala Yeung comment is great hint.

I added this sentence in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/", // add this line.
```

Comment: Can you also show us the `composer.json` file that you uses?

Comment: Your comment is great hint!!, I added        
            "App\\": "src/", under "psr-4":  I will update the article